# O365 - Python Authentication

Tags: python, authentication

I am trying to Authenticate [O365 Mail Rest API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) using Python 3 urllib, I am not able to find any samples using basic authentication.  When using browser it does ask for authentication through interactive windows.  How to achieve the same using urllib.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication based on oAuth [requires a user interaction in order to authenticate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/common-app-authentication-tasks):

> The authorization code is sent back to the application after the user
>   has been redirected to the authorization end point and authenticated.

So no basic authentication, you have to go though the oAuth process.

A similar problem on the Google platform is handled in various ways, one of them being [user-based authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#clientside) but there is also provisionning for [token based ones](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount) (no user interaction)

Comment: I ran into http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2014/02/23/call-o365-using-csom-with-a-console-application.aspx after asking the question.  Wondering if there is a way to do this in python